# google sheet importxml function not fetching data from amazon product

Tags: xml

We want to get data from below url

https://www.amazon.in/Indian-Economy-English-Services-Administrative/dp/9355321139/ref=d_pd_sbs_sccl_2_3/257-6413224-2585305?pd_rd_w=aJLqk&content-id=amzn1.sym.02182ec1-65c5-4957-978b-1e230c9c10a7&pf_rd_p=02182ec1-65c5-4957-978b-1e230c9c10a7&pf_rd_r=ZYMEBJZBV37DGC66PX9A&pd_rd_wg=z2zIX&pd_rd_r=306388a5-f491-4005-b249-25f519bab556&pd_rd_i=9355321139&psc=1

we are using the below formula
=importxml(B1, "//span[@class='a-size-medium a-color-price']"))
where B1 is the url which we have given on top

when we have change the span class for getting second value, we are getting #N/A
=importxml(B1, "//span[@class="a-size-small a-color-secondary mbc-delivery']")

Note : We want only table/data which heading are "Other Sellers on Amazon", its comes on right side after add to cart and buy new

we just want Price, Delivery charges and sold by

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

#### Part 1

Using a cleaned URL in A1:

`https://www.amazon.in/Indian-Economy-English-Services-Administrative/dp/9355321139`

By inspecting the elements, we can find the correct id's.

#### Part 2

Starting with the raw data:

`=importxml($A$1, "//div[@id='mbc']/div")`

Further analysis then allows us to find just the data you are looking for:

`=importxml($A$1, "//div[@id='mbc']/div/div/span[2]")`

Then, with the next div, we get a table, from which we can then pull just the required columns and sort them:
(final formula #1)

`=QUERY(importxml($A$1, "//div[@id='mbc']/div/div/span[2]/div"),"select Col4,Col1,Col3 order by Col4 asc",0)`

#### Part 3

If we want to get the ratings, starting with the raw data:

`=importxml($A$1, "//div[@class='a-box mbc-offer-row pa_mbc_on_amazon_offer']")`

Further analysis gets the data we want:

`=importxml($A$1, "//div[@class='a-box mbc-offer-row pa_mbc_on_amazon_offer']/div/div[3]")`

And, as with the Part 1 example, again we use a div and QUERY:
(final formula #2)

`=QUERY(importxml($A$1, "//div[@class='a-box mbc-offer-row pa_mbc_on_amazon_offer']/div/div[3]/div"),"select Col4,Col5 order by Col2 asc",0)`

[image]